# Replace variable in text file with another variable

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a variable to a specific spot in a text file.

So far I have the variable generation part done, but when I open the text file to see the result, the `${at}` placeholder has been replaced with `${assetTag}` and not the value of the variable.

```
set -x # Print each line of script

set -e # Print error codes for debugging

serialNum=$(dmidecode -s chassis-asset-tag) 

assetTag=$(awk -e '$1 == "'"$serialNum"'"{print $2; q}' /tmp/AssetTag.txt)

cat /tmp/BIOS.txt | sed -e "s/{$aT}/$assetTag/" >> /tmp/BIOS.txt

exit  0
```

So the idea is that I compare the `$serialNum` to a file containing Serial Numbers and Asset Tags.  From there I write the corresponding Asset Tag to `$assetTag`.  After that I need to replace the `$aT` placeholder in the Text file with the `$assetTag` value and save the file for uploading into the system.

```
BIOS.txt excerpt

... <br>
Asset Tracking Number <br>
    ${aT} <br>
Ownership Tag <br>

Product Name <br>
    Thin Client <br>
...<br>


BIOS.txt excerpt after running script

... <br>
Asset Tracking Number <br>
    ${assetTag} <br>
Ownership Tag <br>

Product Name <br>
    Thin Client <br>
...<br>
```

Edit:

Part of the reason I am trying to edit the file is that the script engine I am using has a max of 4096 characters.  In the past I did a "cat >/tmp/Rename.txt << EOL" and simple wrote out the entire file in the script engine.  That however puts me at the limit so I have no more space to add code.  So, if I can edit an existing file that I copied to the Thin Client... I can save lines in the script for actual code and not file construction.

Edit:

Ok, so I found a carriage return at the end of the Asset Tag in the Asset_Tag.txt file.  so that is causing the current headache.

```
assetTag=$(awk -e '$1 == "'"$serialNum"'"{print $2; q}' /tmp/AssetTag.txt)

sed -e "s/@aT@/$assetTag/" /tmp/T630_BIOS.txt > /tmp/BIOS.txt
```

So the question is do I need a `tr -d '\r'` somewhere.  In the assetTag declaration?

Comment: You seemed to mixed up the syntax from both `sed` and `awk`. The `-e`, `q` constructs are specific to `sed`

Comment: @Inian  Hmmm... that line of code actually works as expected, the line below it is the one that is giving me issues.

Comment: `q` in `awk` simply says "get the value of the variable q and then ignore it". You should use `exit` if you want the script to terminate early. What does an actual line of `/tmp/BIOS.txt` look like before and after running `sed`? Also, you appear to be appending to `/tmp/BIOS.txt` rather than overwriting it.

Comment: @jhnc  I would imagine that appending is the way I want to go.  The file contains all the standard configuration changes that I need to make, the Asset Tracking Number is the only thing that I need to change.  Unless there is a way to read the entire file into a variable, update the place holder and then rewrite the file.  Appending seems to be the simpler method.

Comment: There is. `sed` can do "in-place" edits if you pass the `-i` option.

Comment: Looks like you've added an example of the initial BIOS.txt. Do you have one of the output? Your first paragraph has various inconsistencies with your code and the BIOS.txt you've provided.

Comment: You have `-x` enabled. What does this line print: `cat /tmp/BIOS.txt | sed -e "s/{$aT}/$assetTag/" >> /tmp/BIOS.txt` when it's being executed?

Comment: @AaronDigulla  the code appears to run, but there is no change to the text file.

Comment: Please add the output which you see to your question. It should display the contents of the variable `assetTag` instead of `$assetTag`. So you should see `sed -e "s/{$aT}/foo/" ` but not `sed -e "s/{$aT}/$assetTag/" ` Is that correct?

Comment: It's not clear how the sed command shown can produce the output shown given where the braces appear. Also, the first `$` should be escaped. Try: `sed -i -e "s/\${aT}/$assetTag/" BIOS.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a dangerous operation:

```
cat file | cmd >> file
```

It will both open the file for reading and modifying. If the OS didn't stop you, it would be an endless loop (cat reading something, cmd adding to the file, cmd reading that new input ...).

I would suggest that you write the output to a new file to avoid all kinds of weird problems.

That said, the pattern `{$aT}` will never match the input `${aT}`. To match the input, you need this regexp: `\${aT}` but you're using double quotes, so BASH might eat the backslash before `sed` can see it. Check the debug output which `set -x` provides. Make sure the backslash is still there. If it doesn't work, try `\\${aT}` or single quotes - but single quotes will mess with expanding `$assetTag`, so you'll need the same double-single-quote trick which you used in the `awk` script.

That's why many BASH-based template engines use a different prefix like `@` instead of `$`: `@aT@` (no curly braces) or `@{aT}`

Or this might be even more simple:

```
cat header.tmpl > /tmp/BIOS.txt
echo "$assetTag" >> /tmp/BIOS.txt
cat footer.tmpl >> /tmp/BIOS.txt
```

i.e. instead of complex `sed` scripts, just build the output from fragments.

Comment: I had change "echo "$assetTag" >> /tmp/BIOS.txt" to "echo -e "$assetTag\n" >> /tmp/BIOS.txt".  There was issues with importing the finished file, getting the carriage return in there seems to fix the problem.

Comment: well that was premature.  Did some more testing and now I am back to it not updating the bios.  It has something to do with the joining of the footer after $assetTag.  if I go into the file and deleted the return and re-add it after the Asset Tag I can import the file.  I thought that adding the return during the appending of @assetTag would fix it, but now I get a return space and the update fails.  So the code is working, but there's something else going on.

Comment: the carriage returns in my file are cause the current headache.  Will "tr -d '\r'" placed somewhere help, or am I barking up the wrong try?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the fix.  Once the carriage return is removed the file is appended correctly and the BIOS updater works without error.  Thanks Aaron Digulla for pointing my in the right direction!

```
serialNum=$(dmidecode -s chassis-asset-tag)
aTag=$(awk -e '$1 == "'"$serialNum"'"{printf $2; q}' /tmp/AssetTag.txt)

assetTag=$(echo $aTag | tr -d '\r' )

sed -e "s/@aT@/$assetTag/" /tmp/BIOS.txt > /tmp/BIOS_new.txt
```

Comment: Check `/tmp/AssetTag.txt` for CR characters. `awk` treats CR as a normal character , only space (ASCII 0x20) is used as field separator and LF (0x0a) as line separator. The good news is that you can configure `awk` to use CRLF as line separator with `awk ... 'BEGIN{RS="\r\n"} ...'`. Then `aTag` should be clean.